# Splitting the full name in Prefix, First Name, Middle Name and Last Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parsing, substring, charindex

I am trying to split a full name with `Prefix`, `First Name`, `Middle Name` and `Last Name` using SQL Server.

I have tried the following but it is not working properly as desired output is not correct.

**Code**

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    ID,
    FullName,
    SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName)) AS Full_Name,
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)) AS Prefix,
    SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1) FirstName,
    RIGHT(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - 1) AS Last_Name,
    LEN(SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([FullName)) - CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1)) AS FirstNameChar
FROM
    Names WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    (FullName LIKE 'Mr %' OR 
     FullName LIKE 'Mrs %' OR  
     FullName LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
     FullName LIKE 'Ms %' OR
     FullName LIKE 'Dr %')
```

Current output:

| ID | FullName | Prefix | FirstName | Last_Name | FirstNameChar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Mr s t Fenech | Mr | s t | Fenech | 4 |

Required output:

| ID | FullName | Prefix | FirstName | Middle_Name | Last_Name | FirstNameChar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Mr s t Fenech | Mr | s | t | Fenech | 1 |

I want to remove the spaces from before the first name and Last Name as can be see the FirstNameChar is 4 when actually should be 1 and be able to split also the middle name.

Anyone can help with this?

Reference to question on stackoverflow:
[SQL- Get the substring after first space and second space in separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399366/sql-get-the-substring-after-first-space-and-second-space-in-separate-columns)

[SQL: parse the first, middle and last name from a fullname field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159567/sql-parse-the-first-middle-and-last-name-from-a-fullname-field)

[Parse Prefix First Middle Last Suffix from full name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916945/parse-prefix-first-middle-last-suffix-from-full-name)

Comment: The simple answer is, you don't. [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) This question has been asked many times, and the truth is that unless you ask the person how their name is split up, you will always get it wrong.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

This query is applicable for all combinations. As prefix with a space is mandatory so can check with (first_name) or (first_name & last_name) or (first_name & middle_name & last_name) with prefix.

```
    SELECT TOP 10
     ID
     , FullName
     , SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) - 1) Prefix
     , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) = 0 
               THEN NULL
            ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) = 0 
                                                                      THEN LEN(FullName)
                                                                   ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) - 1
                                                              END)) 
       END FirstName
     , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName))) = 0
               THEN NULL
            ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), 
               CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) = 0
                       THEN LEN(FullName)
                    ELSE ((CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName)))) - 1) END)
       END MiddleName
     , CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName))) > 0
               OR CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) > 0)
               THEN CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))), LEN(FullName))) = 0
                            THEN RIGHT(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - 1)
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName), LEN(FullName))) + 1 + CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))), LEN(FullName))
                    END
            ELSE NULL
       END LastName
     , LEN(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) = 0 
                     THEN NULL
                  ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) = 0 
                                                                          THEN LEN(FullName)
                                                                       ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))) - 1
                                                                  END)) 
             END) FirstNameChar
FROM dbo.fullNameTest
WHERE
    (FullName LIKE 'Mr %' OR 
     FullName LIKE 'Mrs %' OR  
     FullName LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
     FullName LIKE 'Ms %' OR
     FullName LIKE 'Dr %');
```

Also check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4a02827d400ac4cadad852bbae96c57

Comment: Hi @alphasqrd: Please check my answer. I think it'll meet your expectations. Though it's very difficult to splitting names because of their formation. I've handled here few name like Mr Lionel Messi, Mrs Van Dar Sar, Miss Lara, Dr Devi Shetti, & Mr Patrick D-DAR WAK CICILEN. Please check from above url where you'll get query with table definition and feel free to ask if any query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IF you do know that the names are always formatted the same (e.g., [prefix][space][first][space][middle][space][last] ), you can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Mr s t Fenech', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Mr s t Fenech') + 1, LEN('Mr s t Fenech')) AS Full_Name
, REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 1)) AS Prefix
, REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 2)) AS FirstName
, REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 3)) AS MiddleName
, REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 4)) AS LastName
, LEN(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 1))) AS PrefixLen
, LEN(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 2))) AS FirstNameLen
, LEN(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 3))) AS MiddleNameLen
, LEN(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('Mr s t Fenech'), ' ', '.'), 4))) AS LastNameLen
```

But replace `'Mr s t Fenech'` with `FullName`.

Comment: Try this with Lord Andrew Lloyd Webber and you'll incorrectly define his middle name as "Lloyd" and his surname as "Webber".

Comment: *"Like I said:"*?

Comment: @Larnu Like I said:  
> IF you do know that the names are always formatted the same. . .  
`Ms Jamie Lynn Marie Spears` is another that will not work correctly. Saying, "The simple answer is, you don't," because there are outliers is like saying don't write any code because something can break your code.   I edited my answer for clarification.